# Storing Objects in SQLite. Is It Possible?

Tags: android, sqlite, ios4, serialization, windows-phone

I have a very complicated issue, but if I can do this, then I will basically solve it in a blow.
Basically, I'm creating an application that at first will run in both iOS and Android, and later possibly for Blackberry and Windows Phone. The problem is, that I will use Dropbox to keep all these devices in sync. The data I need to persist needs to be stored in a SQLite database (ideally, since I can't use Core Data in all the devices and XML is hard to work with  in all platforms). I will create a custom object (in C++, or a struct, or anything I need to create as long as I can make this work in all platforms), and I want to be able to store the raw C++ object in the database and later read it's data in Android (and Blackberry and WP later).

So basically, my question is, can I store raw C++ objects in a SQLite database? And therefore be able to read them on Android and Windows Phone? It sounds like a silly question since Android programming is done in Java and WP is done in C#, and that's what makes me doubt whether my C++ objects could be read from the database with little to no problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that it could be something like dumping binary data -an struct for i.e.- and the answer is yes (blob datatype).

Anyway, if I were doing something like that, I'd store encoded json in a text db field, for the sake of simplicity and portability. Keep in mind that this choice depends on many facts, for example how often the db will be accessed to retrieve/save these objects, or how big are the objects going to be, etc etc.

Hope this helps

Comment: Yes I have considered JSON but I'm not entirely sure if it will fulfill my needs. Think of a contacts database, that's as often as my data would need to be accessed and stored.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds almost like there are two questions here, I can probably answer the first but am not so sure about the second.  Your first question, can you store a compiled C++ object into SQlite, the answer would be yes.  SQLite has a BLOB data type where you can store binary objects and it won't attempt to do any validation on them, it will just store and return them however it gets them (no validation at all).  That's totally irrespective to what language you're programming in, because Java and C# don't need to know, or care, what's in those objects.

As for what I interpret your second question to be, can I execute these binary objects, my inclination is to say no.  I don't think there is any mechanism, at least in Android, to execute these binary objects once you pull it out of SQLite.  The NDK lets you compile and build native code, but I don't know of any way to dynamically load a native object.  Especially since you'd have to compile it for all your desired targets

Hope it helps,
David